# Joining three tables and trying to get null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables: tblProduct, lkpFoodgroup, tblCustomer. And one junction table: jctCustomerFoodgroup

The columns are like this:

```
**tblProduct**
+---+----------------+
|PK |int_ProductID   |
|FK |int_FoodgroupID |
|   |str_ProductName |
+---+----------------+

**lkpFoodgroup**
+---+-------------------+
|PK |int_FoodgroupID    |
|   |str_FoodgroupHandle|
+---+-------------------+

**tblCustomer**
+---+----------------+
|PK |int_CustomerID  |
|   |str_CustomerName|
+---+----------------+

**jctCustomerFoodgroup**
+---+----------------+
|PK |int_CustomerID  |
|PK |int_FoodgroupID |
|   |int_ProductID   |
+---+----------------+
```

The simplest of these tables is the lookup:

```
**lkpFoodgroup**
+---------------+-------------------+
|int_FoodgroupID|str_FoodgroupHandle|
+---------------+-------------------+
|1              |fruit              |
|2              |meat               |
|3              |bread              |
|4              |cheese             |
+---------------+-------------------+
```

Next is Customer:

```
**tblCustomer**
+----------------+-------------------+
|int_CustomerID  |str_CustomerName   |
+----------------+-------------------+
|1               |Bob                |
|2               |Sally              |
|3               |Jane               |
|4               |Billy              |
+----------------+-------------------+
```

There can be many products with the same Foodgroup on tblProduct. Also there can be some product Foodgroups with no products in them:

```
**tblProduct**
+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
|int_ProductID  |int_FoodgroupID  |str_ProductName |
+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
|1              |1                |apple           |
|2              |1                |banana          |
|3              |1                |orange          |
|4              |1                |pear            |
|5              |2                |chicken         |
|6              |2                |beef            |
|7              |2                |fish            |
|8              |2                |turkey          |
|9              |3                |white           |
|10             |3                |wheat           |
+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

The PK on the junction table is a combined int_CustomerID and int_FoodgroupID - which means that any customer can only choose one Product per Foodgroup:

```
**jctCustomerFoodgroup**
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------------+
|int_CustomerID |int_FoodgroupID  |int_ProductID |  --meaning             |
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------------|
|1              | 1               |1             | --Bob, fruit, apple    |
|1              | 2               |6             | --Bob, meat, beef      |
|1              | 3               |9             | --Bob, bread, white    |
|2              | 1               |3             | --Sally, fruit, orange |
|2              | 2               |5             | --Sally, meat, chicken |
|3              | 1               |3             | --Jane, fruit, orange  |
|3              | 3               |9             | --Jane, bread, white   |
|3              | 2               |6             | --Jane, meat, beef     |
+---------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------------+
```

I am looking for a query which will give me results like this:

```
**spGetCustomerProductSelections(1) --Get Bob's choices**
+----------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------+
|int_CustomerID  |int_FoodgroupID|str_FoodgroupHandle|int_ProductID|str_ProductName|
+----------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------+
|1               |1              |fruit              |1            |apple          |
|1               |2              |meat               |6            |beef           |
|1               |3              |bread              |9            |white          |
|1               |4              |cheese             |null         |null           |
+----------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------+

**spGetCustomerProductSelections(2) --Get Sally's choices**
+----------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------+
|int_CustomerID  |int_FoodgroupID|str_FoodgroupHandle|int_ProductID|str_ProductName|
+----------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------+
|2               |1              |fruit              |3            |orange         |
|2               |2              |meat               |5            |chicken        |
|2               |3              |bread              |null         |null           |
|2               |4              |cheese             |null         |null           |
+----------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------+

**spGetCustomerProductSelections(4) --Get Billy's choices**
+----------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------+
|int_CustomerID  |int_FoodgroupID|str_FoodgroupHandle|int_ProductID|str_ProductName|
+----------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------+
|4               |1              |fruit              |null         |null           |
|4               |2              |meat               |null         |null           |
|4               |3              |bread              |null         |null           |
|4               |4              |cheese             |null         |null           |
+----------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Any help?

Comment: You will get more traction if you generated the create and insert statements instead of just data.

Comment: [WTF much](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/adjYour_adjDaily_nCup_prOf_adjAkWTF.aspx)?

Comment: as ProductID is the primary key for product, the junction table CustomerFoodGroup should be CustomerProduct with only the ProductID unless you have business rules that allow you to purchase a product against a different food group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, do not name your procedures beginning with "sp".  It will start searching in the master database and only later come back to your database.

DDL for your schema and data

```
create table lkpFoodgroup
(int_FoodgroupID int, str_FoodgroupHandle varchar(max))
insert lkpFoodgroup values
(1,'fruit'),
(2,'meat'),
(3,'bread'),
(4,'cheese');

create table tblCustomer
(int_CustomerID int, str_CustomerName varchar(max))
insert tblCustomer values
(1,'Bob'),
(2,'Sally'),
(3,'Jane'),
(4,'Billy');

create table tblProduct
(int_ProductID int, int_FoodgroupID int, str_ProductName varchar(max))
insert tblProduct values
(1,'1','apple'),
(2,'1','banana'),
(3,'1','orange'),
(4,'1','pear'),
(5,'2','chicken'),
(6,'2','beef'),
(7,'2','fish'),
(8,'2','turkey'),
(9,'3','white'),
(10,'3','wheat');

create table jctCustomerFoodgroup
(int_CustomerID int, int_FoodgroupID int, int_ProductID varchar(max))
insert jctCustomerFoodgroup values
(1,'1','1'),
(1,'2','6'),
(1,'3','9'),
(2,'1','3'),
(2,'2','5'),
(3,'1','3'),
(3,'3','9'),
(3,'2','6');
```

The Stored Proc code

```
create proc uspGetCustomerProductSelections @customerID int as
select c.int_CustomerID, l.int_FoodgroupID, l.str_FoodgroupHandle, j.int_ProductID, p.str_ProductName
from tblCustomer c
cross join lkpFoodgroup l
left join jctCustomerFoodgroup j on j.int_CustomerID = c.int_CustomerID and j.int_FoodgroupID = l.int_FoodgroupID
left join tblProduct p on p.int_ProductID = j.int_ProductID
where c.int_CustomerID = @customerID
```

Sample execution

```
exec uspGetCustomerProductSelections 1
```

Output

```
int_CustomerID int_FoodgroupID str_FoodgroupHandle  int_ProductID  str_ProductName
-------------- --------------- ---------------------------------------------------
1              1               fruit                1              apple
1              2               meat                 6              beef
1              3               bread                9              white
1              4               cheese               NULL           NULL
```

Comment: Yeah I thought the rule was I can't name them sp_ - I thought sp is fine.

Comment: There's also no need for hungarian notation. You don't need to name something with a `tbl` prefix just because it's a table; use meaningful names.

Comment: Its technically and functionally useless but WRT code literacy and readability it serves a purpose. Its also part of our development standards.

Comment: The hungarian notation does serve a purpose when you use it to denote tables that are not "just" tables e.g. junction and lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You should use outer joins (left, right or full). These joins will include null values.